# Do Time Capsules still work with macOS 10.14 (Mojave)

Tags: time-machine, mojave, time-capsule

Do Apple Time Capsules still work with macOS 10.14 (Mojave).

More specific: Can I use them for wireless Time Machine backups without jumping through hoops I would not have to with Mac OS X 10.6 (the last OS I used with a Time Capsule).

If not all of them work, which do?

Comment: This looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info), so can you describe in more details which problem you are trying to solve here (without already making assumptions about the feasibility of a specific way)?

Comment: Yes, I already edited my question.

Comment: Just voted to reopen, it might take a while

Comment: Time capsules are just NAS drives. They work over the open samba protocal built into macOS and Windows. They will absolutely work. Just mount the drive and set as a time machine disk. Boom done.

Comment: @Wowfunhappy SMB (for which samba is only an open-source implementation of, and not the name of the protocol) is not necessarily used for Time Machine backups to a Time Capsule; AFP is what is preferred for this purpose. A Time Capsule might still provide access over SMB for compatibility with non-AFP clients (e.g. Windows).

Comment: @chrstphrchvz Is that still true? I was under the impression Apple deprecated AFP some time back.

Comment: @Wowfunhappy you're right; I should say AFP *was* preferred, particularly prior to the improvements in recent SMB protocol versions to properly support Time Machine, and the discontinuation of AirPort/Time Capsule products (in favor of third-party Time Machine-over-SMB products).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an old Time Capsule that I’ve had for years.  Recently, I updated my laptop to Mojave and my Time machine backups still continue to work with the Time Capsule.  So the answer is, yes Mojave works with Time Capsules.  One thing to note is that Time Machine can only backup to HFS+ formatted disks.  So make sure that the Time Capsule disk is formatted as HFS+.  Which, I think, is its default format.